# How to retrieve/negotiate the supported Security Methods and Authentication Methods of a SMTP-Server

Tags: c#, smtp

I am using C# (.NET 4.0) and the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Class in order to send an EMail to a SMTP-Server.
For now i'm able to actual send an EMail to the SMTP-Server and see it immediatly in my Inbox-Folder of Thunderbird.

This Test was without specifiying any Authentication Methods nor Security Methods.
But usually SMTP-Server requires some kind of Authentication, i assume.

I wonder, whether it is possible to ask the SMTP-Server, what Authentication Methods it supports and afterwards negotiate to use the desired one.
I'm thinking of something like asking the SMTP-Server about the supported Authentication Methods and get back a list of e.g.:

- No Authentication
- Password, plaintext
- Password, crypted
- Kerberos
- NTLM

Accordingly for the Security Methode of the Connection:

- No Security on the Connection
- STARTTLS
- SSL/TLS

Is there a Way to programmatically retrieve the supported Methods from a SMTP-Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not through the .NET class; rather, you'll need to use a socket-level connection to send the appropriate EHLO request to the server and then parse the response.

Details on the socket programming you'll need are here: [How to validate SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955431/how-to-validate-smtp-server)

You'll want to parse the response from the server. The Wikipedia entry on SMTP AUTH has a useful sample dialog: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication

Utilities like Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) can be handy debugging this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. I was able to get the supported Methods via the mentioned Socket-level Connection. :)